# @Autowired BasicDataSource Multiple times Usage

Tags: spring, initialization, datasource, autowired

I have a class with the following code

```
@Repository
public class MySQLDao {

    /** The datasource. */
    @Autowired
    private BasicDataSource datasource;
}
```

There are multiple classes where MySQLDao bean needs to be injected. Say there are four classes classA,classB,classC and classD. Each of these classes will have the following injection

```
@Autowired
MySQLDao mySQLDao
```

My question is does the use of multiple autowired in these classes cause the basic data source to be reinitialized again? If so is there an alternative to this?

TIA

Comment: There is only a single datasource (at least by default unless you have configured it otherwise). Also you should use `DataSource` instead of `BasicDataSource`. Program to interfaces not concrete classes.

Comment: I am using a Single DataSource. My question is related to usage of @Autowired here. Will autowiring MySQLDao in multiple classes affect initialization or injection of BasicDataSource in any way?

Comment: No it isn't... As mentioned there is a single instance of both the datasource and the dao... It doesn't matter how often you inject that. (At least that is the default behavior if you configured things otherwise then it depends, but that isn't apparent from your code).